# Creating custom JSP tags

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, taglib

In my JSP there is code:

```
<img src="<c:out value="${requestScope['img_url']}"/>"/>
```

I would like to replace it with something like this:

```
<xyz:img src="${requestScope['img_url']}"/>
```

I tried [Struts Taglib](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-taglib), but it requires [Struts](https://struts.apache.org/). Is there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article helped me to find a very simple solution: [Encapsulating Reusable Content Using Tag Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html)

1. Create file WEB-INF/tags/img.tag
2. Add to JSP this header: `<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="xyz" %>`
3. Just use it :)

Answer (score 3):

This is just *custom JSP tags*. There is a great [Sun/Oracle tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20101027005446/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/WebAppDev3/) (archived page) and lots of other great resources out there.

Here are some of the Oracle's resources:

- [Custom Tags in JSP Pages](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html) (the official Java EE 5 Tutorial)
- [Understanding and Creating Custom JSP Tags](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24388/quickstart.htm) (the official Oracle WebLogic Server documentation)

Comment: @Antonio Thanks, I've added an archive link for the previous URL.